# C# datagrid index was out of range

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid

keep getting the error for this line:

```
var imagePath = dataGrid1.SelectedItems[5].ToString();
```

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

Trying to store a cell from my datagrid in a var/string (it holds a path+filename) so I can delete it via ftp.

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var imagePath = dataGrid1.SelectedItems[5].ToString();
        Student selected = dataGrid1.SelectedItem as Student;
        if (selected == null)
            MessageBox.Show("You must select a student");
        else
        {
            if (MessageBoxResult.Yes == MessageBox.Show("Are you sure", "delete student",
                MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Warning))
            {
                FTPdelete(imagePath, "Administrator", "commando");
                Class1.DeleteStudent(selected);
                Window_Loaded(null, null);
            }
        }
    }
    private void FTPdelete(String imagePath, String inUsername, String inPassword)
    {
        var req = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(imagePath);
        req.Proxy = null;
        req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(inUsername, inPassword);

        req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;

        req.GetResponse().Close();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Looks like you might want the 6th **column** of the selected item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've got it mixed up between SelectedItems and SelectedItem - [SelectedItems should return a IEnumerable of the selected items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.selecteditems%28VS.95%29.aspx) - it looks like you're trying to access a column of the SelectedItem.

If Student has an ImagePath, you could re-order a little and just have:

```
Student selected = dataGrid1.SelectedItem as Student;
var imagePath = selected.ImagePath;
```

Comment: my datagrid looks like this | ID | Number | FirstName | LastName | Current | imagePath[5] im trying to get the users image path name from the datagrid then fire it into my ftpdelete

Comment: if i do that I get an error saying cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

Comment: Cast the object into a DataGridColumn, maybe that will help

Comment: Sorry about the real-time editing of my answers - you were almost there on your own steam.

Comment: cristo can you help out here?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4359800/ftp-handler-page-call-string-from-aspx-help-with-method-to-initialize-handler-pa