# FTP handler page, call string from aspx help with method to initialize handler page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, c#-4.0, httphandler

Hey guys, tryed to clean up my last post so here it goes.

I have a handler page in my asp.net project that is "trying" to handle a ftp download request.

GetImage.ashx.cs

```
public class GetImage : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        {

            // method for calling PhotoPath from Database.aspx.cs
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri());
            // (new Uri) I would like to just store "photopath" in here as it has the ftp plus the filename in it
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

            try
            {
                FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
                byte[] bytes = new byte[2048];

                int i = 0;
                MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();

                do
                {

                    i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                    mStream.Write(bytes, 0, i);
                } while (i != 0);

                context.Response.ClearHeaders();
                context.Response.ClearContent();
                context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
// Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "image/jpeg"); this is from the database.aspx page not sure if its correct 
                    context.Response.BinaryWrite(mStream.GetBuffer());
                }
                catch (WebException wex)
                {

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("An error occurred: " + ex);

            }

        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

}

On my page that holds my gridview I have a method to extract data from one of my cells, this cell contains the ftp path and filename of the image im trying to show in my image control:

Database.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){

        Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");

    }

    protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string PhotoPath = "";
        // Get the currently selected row. Because the SelectedIndexChanging event
        // occurs before the select operation in the GridView control, the
        // SelectedRow property cannot be used. Instead, use the Rows collection
        // and the NewSelectedIndex property of the e argument passed to this 
        // event handler.
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[GridView1.SelectedIndex];

        PhotoPath = row.Cells[5].Text;
        // how do I send photopath to my handler page?
        //TextBox1.Text = PhotoPath;
    }
}
```

}

In my handler page I want to call the string "PhotoPath" and place it in my ftwwebrequest in my handler page:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(PhotoPath));
```

Ive set my image control ImageUrl to ~/GetImage.ashx and will need some help with code to call the handler from my database page?

Can any one help because ive been stuck on this for ages?

Comment: Please don't repost questions. You should have edited the prev one. Or closed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to pass PhotoPath to the ASHX handler using the querystring.  You should then read the parameter from the querystring and pass it to `WebRequest.Create`
- You should not swallow exceptions
- You don't need to clear the response
- You should copy the FtpWebResponse directly to the HttpResponse; you don't need an intermediate MemoryStream
- The `ContentType` property tells the browser what kind of file you're sending.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME_type

Comment: @Garith: That's what you'd write in the ASHX.  You would then use a URL like `/FtpForwarder.ashx?PhotoPath=/path/to/ftp/file`.

Comment: Ive re-edited my post still dont think I have the photo path bit correct. :(

Comment: @Garrith: Do you understand how images  work in HTML? You need to add PhotoPath to a URL sent to the client.

Comment: Sorry Slak im utterly lost atm, photopath is a cell in my gridview that already contains the path+filename to my ftp server

Comment: @Garrith: You need to make a tag that looks like `<img src="/FtpForwarder.ashx?PhotoPath=/path/to/ftp/file" />`.  You probably need to learn the basics of HTML and HTTP.

Comment: <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" DescriptionUrl="~/GetImage.ashx" 
            Height="264px" ImageUrl="~/GetImage.ashx" Width="302px" />

Comment: @Garrith: Change that to something like `ImageUrl="<%# "~/FtpForwarder.ashx?PhotoPath=" + Server.UrlEncode(something) %>"`

Comment: the image url is already set up to get it from the handler page ImageUrl="~/GetImage.ashx"

Comment: @Garrith: But you need to pass PhotoPath in the handler's URL.