# easy way to show images in asp.net from ftp server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ftp

is there any easy way to show images in asp.net page from a ftp server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4359800/34397

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<img src="ftp://..."/>
```

Comment: This requires that you send credentials to the client.

Comment: I was under the impression that you can use the above technique if the public has the right permissions.

Comment: The ftp server would need to allow anonymous access.

Comment: what about `<img src=username:password ftp />`''  also how do you store a string in the <img src> from cs code?

Comment: woohoo got it working!! now I just need to find a way to use a string like src = "path" but not sure how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If your password is secure then follow below steps :-

You really should create an FTP account that only has access to the folder with the images on your FTP server. Do that as soon as possible.

For a better overall solution, either synchronize the images to your webserver, or write an HTTP handler that will fetch the image server-side and streams the bytes to the client as if the image was on your server. Have a look at System.Net.FtpWebRequest for the second solution.

If you have write access to disk on the web server, you could implement both parts of the solution. So if an image is fetched the first time, write it to disk before sending it to the client. The next time it's requested, simply redirect the request to the image on disk (or dynamically change the URL of the  tag for that product). This way, you build a cache of the images on your web server as time passes. Of course, you need to be able to invalidate the cache in case an image is updated.